# How to delete a pet using swagger.io with reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, swagger, display, http-delete

I have an exam in which I have to create a reactJs frontend app using the server swagger.io as backend. My main problem is that I don't know how to get the list of all the pets that's why I create a json file that contain some data. but when I try to delete a pet I got this error: DELETE http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/2 net::ERR_FAILED.
this is the code :

```
  async function deleteOperation(petId) {
    let result = await fetch(`http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/${petId}`,{
      method: "DELETE"

    });

    result = await result.json()

  }

  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    {  data && data.length>0 && data.map((item)=>

    <div className="card" style={{width: 18 +'rem'}}>
             
    <img src={item.photoUrls} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{width:200, height:200}}/>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">    
      <p>{item.name}</p>
       
     </h5>
      <p className="card-text">{item.status}</p>
      <p>{item?.categorie?.name}</p>
   <span onClick={() => deleteOperation(item.id)}>
    <p>delete</p>

      </span>
      <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary"> </a>
    </div>
    </div>          
    )}
  </div>
  );
```

I would ask if anyone have an idea how to display pets stored in swagger.io because I will have problem in displaying data when I will add new pet. and if anyone of you have an idea about solving deleting issue I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

Upon exploring, I see no direct endpoint to fetch the list of pets. While searching for this issue, I came across https://erichealdwebb.net/wiki/swagger-retrieve-list-of-pets-by-status, where the list of pets is returned based on the query param `status.` So, you can use this approach to list `available,` `pending,` and `sold` pets. Plus, you are using the `HTTP` version, which is throwing the `CORS` error (the error you are facing now is `net::ERR_FAILED.`). Please be careful when using 3rd party URLs and always prefer to use `HTTPS.` You don't have a method for fetching the `pets.` Moreover, you are returning the JSX from the `delete` function. For this use case, you can use the `useState` hook. And I see you are nesting `<p>` within `<h5>` and `<span>` tags. You can directly use the `<p>` tag or the `<h1>` and `<span>` tags. So, finally, your code should look like this,

```html
 <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      const App = () => {
        const url = "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet";
        const [pets, setPets] = React.useState([]);
        const [errorState, setError] = React.useState();
        const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
        const fetchPetsByStatus = async (status) => {
          setLoading(true);
          try {
            const response = await fetch(
              `${url}/findByStatus?status=${status || "available"}`,
              {
                method: "GET",
                mode: "cors",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
              }
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error(data.message);

            setPets(data);
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error.message);
            throw new Error(error);
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        };
        const deletePet = async (petId) => {
          try {
            const result = await fetch(
              `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/pet/${petId}`,
              {
                method: "DELETE",
              }
            );
            const data = await result.json();
            if (data.code === 200) {
              alert("deleted");
              fetchPetsByStatus();
            }
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
          }
        };
        React.useEffect(() => {
          fetchPetsByStatus(/* here you can pass options like 'available', 'pending', and 'sold'*/);
        }, []);
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              padding: "16px",
            }}
          >
            {loading && <h1>Loading</h1>}
            {errorState && errorState}
            {pets &&
              pets.length > 0 &&
              pets.map((pet, ind) => (
                <div
                  key={ind}
                  className="card"
                  style={{ margin: 16, width: 18 + "rem" }}
                >
                  <img
                    src={pet.photoUrls}
                    className="card-img-top"
                    alt="..."
                    style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
                  />
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{pet.name}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{pet.status}</p>
                    <p>{pet?.category?.name}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => deletePet(pet.id)}>delete</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        );
      };

      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
      root.render(<App />);
    </script>
```

This is not the best solution or the perfect solution. There are a lot of other ways. I added the `loading` and 'error`states for you to get a better understanding of the`reactivity` of ReactJS. This is just my preference or my way of approach.

Hope I have helped :)